# Change rowspan value dynamically using Angular js inside a table with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to set the row span value dynamically based on a condition.

The Array I have:

```
 $scope.approvalitems = [
                 { ReqId: '100' Date: '02-02-2015', AssociateID: '346248', },
                 { ReqId: '101' Date: '02-02-2015', AssociateID: '346248', },
                                ------------------------------------------  
                 { ReqId: '102' Date: '06-02-2015', AssociateID: '123456', },
                 { ReqId: '103' Date: '06-02-2015', AssociateID: '123456', },
                 { ReqId: '104' Date: '06-02-2015', AssociateID: '123456', },
                                -------------------------------------------
                 { ReqId: '105', Date: '07-02-2015', AssociateID: '309645',},
                 { ReqId: '106', Date: '07-02-2015', AssociateID: '309645',},
                                --------------------------------------------
                 { ReqId: '107', Date: '08-02-2015', AssociateID: '346248',}
        ];
```

Need to set the row span value =(count of items ) having  both the DATE and AssociateID values same.

I'm unable to structute the table using ng-repeat , tried using group but unable to get the count of unique elements of Date and AssociateID using groupBy in filter . Looking for an approach to solve this.

Need to get like this.

```
Date       AssociateID      Time
-----------|----------|-----------------------
02-02-2015 |346248    | Click here for the time
-----------|----------|
02-02-2015 |346248    |
-----------|----------|----------------------
06-02-2015 |123456    | Click here for the time
-----------|----------|
06-02-2015 |123456    |
-----------|----------|
06-02-2015 |123456    |
-----------|----------|----------------------
07-02-2015 |309645    | Click here for the time
-----------|----------|
07-02-2015 |309645    |
-----------|----------|----------------------   
08-02-2015 |346248    | Click here for the time
```

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshwar33/uae0qery/)

So how to acheive this , should i need to sort it before binding the array , if so pls guide me or is there any better way to acheive this.I'm a newbie to angular js.

Answer (score 1):

In your case i would sort the by using an object as map.

```
$scope.createObjectMap = function () {
        var items = {};
        angular.forEach($scope.approvalitems, function (value, key) {
            if (!items['id' + value.AssociateID]) { // +id because properties shound not begin with numbers
                items['id' + value.AssociateID] = new Array();
            }
            items['id' + value.AssociateID].push(value);
        });
        return items;
    }
```

And then i would use two ng-repeat, first to iterate over the object and th second to iterate over the values (an array).
Take a look to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdsjg2z6/).

If someone have a better solution please let me know.

Comment: why you think `properties shound not begin with numbers`?

Comment: @Grundy I prefer property names witch are valid variable names. Because if often pass data via json to a rest-api and property names witch are not starting with a number make my life easier.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for the answer , but i need to set the value of rowspan  by comparing both AssociateID and Date , or  can i   get the count of similar items ,push it to an array and use it in ng-repeat.will that work ?Thanx for the help

Comment: I'm not sure that i understand your question. You can access the length of "group" in my example (fiddle). http://jsfiddle.net/90n55ctb/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **filter** that will be apply to the `ngRepeat` directive.
But you must be careful with this **digest cycle error** :

> 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

You can get these error because we are returning different objects on each **$digest** cycle, or we are altering the data too many times.

So a good option is to Memoizing Angular filters to stop digest errors. You can use the [_.memoize](https://lodash.com/docs#memoize) method from the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library to make them run faster and avoid nasty digest loops.
Don't forget to include the **lodash** script tag in your html.

So :

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope) {

  $scope.approvalitems = [
          { ReqId: '101', Date: '02-02-2015', AssociateID: '346248', },
           { ReqId: '102', Date: '02-02-2015', AssociateID: '346248', },
           { ReqId: '103', Date: '06-02-2015', AssociateID: '123456', },
           { ReqId: '104', Date: '06-02-2015', AssociateID: '123456', },
           { ReqId: '105', Date: '06-02-2015', AssociateID: '123456', },
           { ReqId: '106', Date: '07-02-2015', AssociateID: '309645', },
           { ReqId: '107', Date: '07-02-2015', AssociateID: '309645', },
           { ReqId: '108', Date: '08-02-2015', AssociateID: '346248', }
  ];

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Filter**

```
(function(){

  function filter(){

    function group(input, search) {

        if (!input) { return; }
        //Create our filtered object
         var filtered = {};
         //Split our search params
         var field = search.split(',');
         //For all input
         input.forEach(function(item) {
           //Retrieve field param by mapping over the item element
           var key = field.map(function(elm){
             return item[elm.replace(/ /g,'')];
           });
           //If our object get the key, retrieve it, otherwise, create an empty array
           filtered[JSON.stringify(key)] = filtered[JSON.stringify(key)] || [];
           //Push item data into our object
           filtered[JSON.stringify(key)].push(item);
         });

       return filtered;
   }

   //Memoize the filter function by using lodash memoize
   return _.memoize(group);

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .filter('group', filter);

})();
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

    <table style="width: 30%" border="3">
       <tr>
           <th>Date</th>
           <th>AssociateID</th>
           <th>SwipeSummary</th>
       </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in approvalitems | group: 'Date,AssociateID'" >
         <td>
            <div ng-repeat="item in value">
              {{item.Date}}
            </div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div ng-repeat="item in value">
              {{item.AssociateID}}
            </div>
         </td>
         <td>
           <span>Click here for time</span>
         </td>
       </tr>

    </table>

 </body>
```

You can see the [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/r4bhfpUaYZL17BUnIsce?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1 . so you say its better to create a custom filter with memozie to avoid exception as the table structure gets iterated many times, also i've changed the correct table structure in the  question,help on that is welcome.

Comment: I dont want the td values in date and associate id grouped inside a single cell , need to be just like a row .only the 'Time' cell to be grouped based on the associateid and date. You can look at the table structure in the question.Thank you